# Backbone.js events not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

When I click a continue button, some text box should shown in a div, but it's not happening. Here is my code.

html file :

```
    <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" id="3continue"
                                        type="button">
```

my javascript file :

```
    events:{
          'click button#3continue': 'displayCoupon'
           },
    initialize: function(){
            var self=this;
           _.bindAll(this,'render','addProductDetails','displayCoupon'); 

            this.collection = new List();
            this.addProductDetails();
        },

   displayCoupon: function(){
      //e.preventDefault();
      console.log("in displayCoupon");
      $('#couponcheck').empty();
      $('#couponcheck').append('<div class="col-xs-8"><input  type="text" class="form-control" id="enterCoupon"></div>');
      $('#couponcheck').append('<div class="col-xs-8"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="couponbutton">Apply</button></div>');


},
```

Comment: Just a tip: you don't need to bind 'displayCoupon' with bindAll, because you are not using `this` in that function. Even in the case you used it, you wouldn't need to bind it, because with `events` hash, the `this` scope is not altered.

Comment: Is that `<button>` inside your view's `el`? Probably it isn't.

Comment: @muistooshort No its not inside view's el

Comment: It has to be or it won't work. Backbone events are handled through event delegation on the view's `el`.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks man, it works. but, already some other id is there in el part, is it possible to add more?

Comment: @muistooshort is it good practice, if i add entire container in "el" section?

Comment: I think you need to spend some time with Backbone tutorials and the documentation. A lot of the Backbone answers around here will cover all this stuff and come with jsfiddle.net demos.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

Html:

```
 <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" id="clickMe"
                                            type="button">
```

Javascript:

```
 events:{
          'click #clickMe': 'displayCoupon'
           },
    initialize: function(){
            var self=this;
           _.bindAll(this,'render','addProductDetails','displayCoupon'); 

            this.collection = new List();
            this.addProductDetails();
        },

   displayCoupon: function(){
      //e.preventDefault();
      console.log("in displayCoupon");
      $('#couponcheck').empty();
      $('#couponcheck').append('<div class="col-xs-8"><input          type="text" class="form-control" id="enterCoupon"></div>');
      $('#couponcheck').append('<div class="col-xs-8"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="couponbutton">Apply</button></div>');


},
```

In your code you have written

```
events:{
       'click button#3continue': 'displayCoupon'
      },
```

try replacing above code with code given below:

```
 events:{
      'click #3continue': 'displayCoupon'
       },
```

Comment: I tried this, but its not working. other click events are working.